# Gulp exclude all files and folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp

I am trying to exclude a task from watching or moving a set of files.

Basically I want to move all the files I set up using the variable all_web_files:

```
gulp.task('move-files', function()
  {
    gutil.log( gutil.colors.bgCyan.bold('Moving Folders to Build'));

    //Move the web files
    gulp.src(all_web_files)
      .pipe(gulp.dest(build));

});
```

then:

```
var     all_web_files = [ 
                        site + '**/*', '!web_server/resources/{assets,assets/**}',
                        ch_core + '**/*',
                        ch_server + '**/*', 
                        ch_server + '!{p4p_api,p4p_api/**}',
                        ch_server + '!{p4p_ebextensions,p4p_ebextensions/**}'
                    ];
```

So basically I want to exclude the assets folder and everything in it as well as the folders p4p_api and p4p_ebextensions and everything in them. Unfortunately those folders keep getting moved over. I suspect I am not excluding them right.

Answer (score 0):

You put your exclamation mark in the wrong place. Try it that way:

```
var all_web_files = [ 
                        ch_core + '**/*',
                        ch_server + '**/*', 
                        '!' + site + '**/*', 'web_server/resources/{assets,assets/**}',                          
                        '!' + ch_server + '{p4p_api,p4p_api/**}',
                        '!' + ch_server + '{p4p_ebextensions,p4p_ebextensions/**}'
                    ];
```

Comment: Ahhhh, I see. That worked for the ` '!' + ch_server + '{p4p_api,p4p_api/**}',
                        '!' + ch_server + '{p4p_ebextensions,p4p_ebextensions/**}'` but assets still come over from `site`

Comment: That's because I missed another exclamation mark, in the first line. Here, I fixed it now.